# confusion about mongodb capped collection

Tags: java, mongodb, collections, statistics

I am new to mongodb. Here is a code snippet:

```
MongoClient mongo = new MongoClient("localhost", 27017);
DB db = mongo.getDB("testdb");
DBCollection collection = db.getCollection("user");
```

for `db.getCollection("user")`, if there is an existing collection named "user", it will return this collection. If "user" does not exit, `getCollection("user")` will create a new collection. Now I want to know what type of collection does `getCollection` create. Does `getCollection` return a capped collection?

I have read mongodb manual:

> You must create capped collections explicitly using the `createCollection()` method.

Does this mean the collection created by `getCollection` is not capped collection?

Also I want to know:

1. What is the max default size for a DBcollection on 32 bit system?
2. What is the max number of collections within a db?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MongoDB does not create a capped collection except through the technique you describe (it could be created through an API or the shell).

*Max default size for a collection?* Around 2GB on a 32 bit system. However, 10gen does not recommend the 32bit build for a production system (see here).

*Maximum number of collections* is a bit more complex, and is best explained by the [documentation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/data-modeling/#large-number-of-collections).

Comment: Thx. Also I want to know where does Mongodb store the data, in hard disk or memory?

Answer (score 0):

Mongodb capped collection has so many restrictions, see the link http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/capped-collections/ . I would recommend TTL rather which helps achieve the same aim. You can find more about TTL here http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/expire-data/.